# Magento: Extension stopped working after transfer to server

Tags: jquery, magento

I worked on a Magento website locally, using the magento sample content. The Magehouse Price SLider extension worked fine. Then I created a fresh installation of Magento on server, installed theme and all CMS Static blocks, and created categories and products myself. Now Ajax Price Slider is not showing up on category page, and in the backend, it is not showing up in System->Configuration page sidebar, as it was appearing on local server.

I checked through online files, all the files/folders are present in their location i.e. app/code/community/Magehouse/Slider

I'm fairly new to Magento extension usage. I don't know how I can debugg the problem. Please advise what should I do.

Comment: may be you forgot to add `etc/module` file for that extension.

Comment: @KingshukDeb you are absolutely right. Quite silly of me to miss out such obvious point. THanks a lot. You can enter this as answer, i'll mark it as correct. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you forgot to add `etc/module` file for that extension

Comment: but take oath that you never ask such silly questions here...please ask some good questions which can help other too..That is Stack overflow meant for. Dont mind.